# How to match date and string from 2 lists (KDB)?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I have two lists:

```
data:
dt                             sym    bid    ask
2017.01.01D05:00:09.140745000  AAPL   101.20 101.30
2017.01.01D05:00:09.284281800  GOOG   801.00 802.00
2017.01.02D05:00:09.824847299  AAPL   101.30 101.40

info:
date          sym    shares    divisor
2017.01.01    AAPL   500       2
2017.01.01    GOOG   100       1
2017.01.02    AAPL   200       2
```

I need to append from "info" the shares and divisor values for each ticker based on the date. How can I achieve this? Below is an example:

```
result:
dt                             sym    bid    ask     shares   divisor
2017.01.01D05:00:09.140745000  AAPL   101.20 101.30  500      2
2017.01.01D05:00:09.284281800  GOOG   801.00 802.00  100      1
2017.01.02D05:00:09.824847299  AAPL   101.30 101.40  200      2
```

Comment: It's much easier for people to test & provide answers if you supply an example that is "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable". See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve In short, it'd be very helpful if you could provide Q expressions to generate your input tables, e.g. with real timestamps not `ts0` etc

Comment: Assume tables cannot be read in a different way or are from some data store

Comment: That's better, but it's much more useful if you can provide a Q expression to set up the tables. e.g. ``data:([] dt:(10?2017.01.01+til 2)+10?.z.t;sym:10?`AAPL`GOOG;bid:100+10?5;ask:105+10?5);info:([] date:2017.01.01 2017.01.01 2017.01.02;sym:`AAPL`GOOG`AAPL;shares:500 100 200;divisor:2 1 2)``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If matching based on an exact date match then you can use [`lj`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/#lj-ljf-left-join). For this to work you will need to create a date column in the `data` table and key `info` by `date` and `sym`. Like so:

```
(update date:`date$dt from data)lj 2!info
dt                            sym  price    date       shares divisor
---------------------------------------------------------------------
2018.02.04D17:25:06.658216000 AAPL 103.9275 2018.02.04 500    2
2018.02.04D17:25:06.658216000 GOOG 105.1709 2018.02.04 100    1
2018.02.05D17:25:06.658217000 AAPL 105.1598 2018.02.05 200    2
2018.02.05D17:25:06.658217000 GOOG 104.0666 2018.02.05
```

You can then delete the `date` column from this output.

Comment: I think you would need to use `2!` to key on `date` and `sym`

Comment: TS, you're a legend. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful for you to use the stepped attribute [ http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/temporal-data/#stepped-attribute ]

This will allow you to have e.g. missing dates from the `info` table and use the "most recent" date instead (so you don't have to have data for every sym every day). For example, without stepped attribute:

```
q)data:([] dt:(10?2017.01.01+til 2)+10?.z.t;sym:10?`AAPL`GOOG;bid:100+10?5;ask:105+10?5)
q)info:([] date:2017.01.01 2017.01.01 2017.01.02;sym:`AAPL`GOOG`AAPL;shares:500 100 200;divisor:2 1 2)
q)(update date:`date$dt from data) lj 2!info
dt                            sym  bid ask date       shares divisor
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2017.01.01D04:04:03.440000000 GOOG 104 105 2017.01.01 100    1
2017.01.01D14:00:02.748000000 GOOG 104 105 2017.01.01 100    1
2017.01.02D09:34:52.869000000 GOOG 102 106 2017.01.02
2017.01.02D16:44:16.648000000 AAPL 100 107 2017.01.02 200    2
2017.01.01D08:48:23.285000000 AAPL 102 108 2017.01.01 500    2
2017.01.02D02:31:11.038000000 AAPL 104 109 2017.01.02 200    2
2017.01.01D05:50:50.463000000 GOOG 104 109 2017.01.01 100    1
2017.01.02D02:13:45.275000000 AAPL 101 107 2017.01.02 200    2
2017.01.01D10:25:30.322000000 AAPL 104 109 2017.01.01 500    2
2017.01.01D14:51:12.687000000 AAPL 103 109 2017.01.01 500    2
```

Note the nulls for `GOOG` on `2017.01.02`. With stepped attribute:

```
q)(update date:`date$dt from data) lj `s#2!`sym xasc `sym`date xcols info
dt                            sym  bid ask date       shares divisor
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2017.01.01D04:04:03.440000000 GOOG 104 105 2017.01.01 100    1
2017.01.01D14:00:02.748000000 GOOG 104 105 2017.01.01 100    1
2017.01.02D09:34:52.869000000 GOOG 102 106 2017.01.02 100    1
2017.01.02D16:44:16.648000000 AAPL 100 107 2017.01.02 200    2
2017.01.01D08:48:23.285000000 AAPL 102 108 2017.01.01 500    2
2017.01.02D02:31:11.038000000 AAPL 104 109 2017.01.02 200    2
2017.01.01D05:50:50.463000000 GOOG 104 109 2017.01.01 100    1
2017.01.02D02:13:45.275000000 AAPL 101 107 2017.01.02 200    2
2017.01.01D10:25:30.322000000 AAPL 104 109 2017.01.01 500    2
2017.01.01D14:51:12.687000000 AAPL 103 109 2017.01.01 500    2
```

Here, `GOOG` gets the values for `2017.01.01` as there is no new value on `2017.01.02`

Answer (score 1):

Could possibly use an aj as well.

```
q)aj[`date`sym;update date:`date$dt from data;info]
dt                            sym  bid ask date       shares divisor
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2017.01.02D07:57:14.764000000 GOOG 101 109 2017.01.02 200    2
2017.01.02D02:31:39.330000000 AAPL 100 105 2017.01.02 200    2
2017.01.02D04:25:17.604000000 AAPL 102 107 2017.01.02 200    2
2017.01.01D01:47:51.333000000 GOOG 104 106 2017.01.01 100    1
2017.01.02D15:50:12.140000000 AAPL 101 107 2017.01.02 200    2
2017.01.01D02:59:16.636000000 GOOG 102 106 2017.01.01 100    1
2017.01.01D14:35:31.860000000 AAPL 100 107 2017.01.01 500    2
2017.01.01D16:36:29.214000000 GOOG 101 108 2017.01.01 100    1
2017.01.01D14:01:18.498000000 GOOG 101 107 2017.01.01 100    1
2017.01.02D08:31:52.958000000 AAPL 102 109 2017.01.02 200    2
```