# How to generate datatable by iterating through multiple lists? (KDB)

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I have a function `quotes[ticker;startDate;endDate]`, and a function `indexConstituents[index;startDate;endDate]` that yield the below:

```
daterange: 2017.12.05,2017.12.06;

quotes'[AAPL;daterange]

date        time    sym    price
2017.12.05  09:45   AAPL   101.20
2017.12.06  09:45   AAPL   102.30

quotes'[GOOG;daterange]

date        time    sym    price
2017.12.05  10:00   GOOG   800.50

quotes'[BBRY;daterange]

date        time    sym    price
2017.12.06  11:15   BBRY   02.10
```

and

```
indexConstituents'[DJIA;daterange]

date        sym    shares   divisor
2017.12.05  AAPL   20       2
2017.12.05  GOOG   5        1
2017.12.06  AAPL   10       1.5
2017.12.06  BBRY   100      1
```

I need a way to run the indexConstituents function as normal to yield a list of constituents over a set of days (as in the second table above), **then fetch the data from table 1 for each constituent**. Finally, I need to join the data from both tables to yield the below:

```
data:
date       time     sym    price    shares    divisor
2017.12.05 09:45    AAPL   101.20   20        2
2017.12.06 09:45    AAPL   101.30   10        1.5
2017.12.05 10:00    GOOG   800.50   5         1
2017.12.06 11:15    BBRY   02.10    200       1
```

Code for the first two tables:

```
([] date:2017.12.05,2017.12.06; time:09:45,09:45; sym:`AAPL,`AAPL; price:101.20,102.30)

([] date:2017.12.05,2017.12.05,2017.12.06,2017.12.06; sym:`AAPL,`GOOG,`AAPL,`BBRY; shares:20f,5f,10f,100f; divisor:2f,1f,1.5f,1f)
```

Comment: Both of those tables combined could never create that third table. Also this seems like a rehash of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48628006/how-to-match-date-and-string-from-2-lists-kdb). Looks like the `lj` or `aj` join approach should still work in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match date and string from 2 lists (KDB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48628006/how-to-match-date-and-string-from-2-lists-kdb)

Comment: To expand on Thomas' first comment - you appear to have a lot more quotes in your final output than are in your initial input

Comment: The first function generates a table for a given ticker. I have a list of tickers I need to iterate over. Will add that to the question

Comment: Hey Fomalhaut - I noticed you're asking a few questions on kdb basics. I did a set of training videos from AquaQ, some of which are now free. Full disclosure: I do now work there, but this is still the training I did, and it was helpful, so you might want to check it out! https://training.aquaq.co.uk/kdb-taster

Comment: Will do. I only went through "Q for Mortals" but am working all day, so little time to read when I have to deliver stuff using KDB >.<. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach is to assign the resultant table from `indexConstituents'[DJIA;daterange]` to a variable, so that we can then pull out the `sym` column and apply `distinct` to it.

You can then use that list of syms as your first argument to the `quotes`.

Finally join the two resultant tables together.

```
idx:indexConstituents'[DJIA;daterange];
q:quotes\:/:[distinct idx`sym;daterange];
q lj 2!idx
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think the issue here is that the sym list changes depending on the day. So the quotes function needs to only fetch a given set of syms if those syms are present on the given dates.

Comment: Would `ij` work instead of `lj`, this should ensure `sym` values not in `idx` are excluded.

Comment: I figured it out using this advice. Thanks to you both.